# Can Maps and Reduces be identified dynamically?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I want to figure out whether there is any software or algorithm which can help in identifying the maps and reduces in a given code on its own.

Answer (score 0):

This is what that happens when you run Hive or Pig queries. You just submit your queries and they automatically get converted into corresponding MR jobs and you get the result without having to do anything additional. Have a look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)(ANother Tool for Language Recognition) which automatically parses a given Hive query into the corresponding MR job. ANTLR is a parser generator for reading, processing, executing, or translating structured text or binary files.

Do you need something else?Apologies if I have get it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I wanted to know that for a given sequential code, is there any way to determine if the code can be converted to a map reduced program